# Geolocation in Ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am working with Geolocation in android for the past 2 week and having the same error over and over no matter how i have tried.
Here is my Code

```
 getCurrentLocation() {


    let options = {timeout: 30000, enableHighAccuracy: false, maximumAge: 3600};
    console.log("Location is Called: ");
    this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(options).then((resp) => {
        console.log("Getting Location : " + resp);
        this.latitude = resp.coords.latitude;
        this.longitude = resp.coords.longitude;
        alert(this.latitude);
        this.getSearch();

    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error getting location', error);
    });
    //   this.getSearch();
    let watch = this.geolocation.watchPosition();
    watch.subscribe((data) => {
        // data can be a set of coordinates, or an error (if an error occurred).
        this.latitude = data.coords.latitude;
        this.longitude = data.coords.longitude;
    });
}


   ionViewDidLoad() {

        this.platform.ready().then(() => this.getCurrentLocation());
    }
```

It works on Browsers using ionic serve but does not work on emulator and android devices

Here is the error from emulator

```
Error getting location PositionError {}code: 3message: "Timeout 
expired"__proto__: PositionError
```

On Devices i get

Device does not have permission

Here is my android manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP" />
```

Comment: are you using geolocation native plugin, remove the options and don't pass anything inside getGeoLocation method and check

Comment: i have removed the options, ionic serve still works. Still does not work on emulate or real android devices

Comment: it wont work on emulator it works on device only

Comment: do you have the required permissions to your device location. is the location on

Comment: Yes!, the location is on

Comment: great . happy coding

Comment: Does your emulator have google play services?

Comment: No. Even on devices, it has not work

Comment: I have observed that it works on Ios but not android